# How do I reverse a list in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I have:

```
clientWB.Sheets(getClientSheetNames("currMonth").ToArray).Copy(After:=devWB.Sheets(1))
```

Function: getClientSheetNames("currMonth") returns a list of String.

I want to select the sheets in reverse order, so I did:

```
clientWB.Sheets(getClientSheetNames("currMonth").Reverse().ToArray).Copy(After:=devWB.Sheets(1))
```

But it gives an error:

> getClientSheetNames("currMonth").Reverse() => Expression does not produce a value

What am I doing wrong? How should I correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried a switcheroo on your calls?

```
getClientSheetNames("currMonth").ToArray.Reverse()
```

Answer (score 3):

`List(Of T).Reverse` is a sub, so it will return nothing (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2.aspx#Y114)). You have to do the reverse first, for example like this:

```
Dim myList As New List(Of String)
myList = getClientSheetNames("currMonth")
myList.Reverse()
clientWB.Sheets(myList.ToArray).Copy(After:=devWB.Sheets(1))
```